# What did I imply to the Fire Keeper?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I am having trouble following the story of Dark Souls 3 and have made a dialogue decision I didn't really understand the implication of. This question contains spoilers:

> I found Fire Keeper eyes in the Untended Graves and gave them to the Fire Keeper, since that seemed like the most logical thing to do to see what happens. Unfortunately, she then asked me a question I can't quite remember whether I wanted to do something and I accepted. Then the music of Firelink Shrine changed and the Fire Keeper asks me to kill her "if I find it in my heart". What exactly did I imply by not refusing and can I reverse this?

I know there are several endings to the game and I feel like I'm on the path for a "bad" one. Please don't spoil the ending for me or what the decision leads to. I'd only like to know what the dialogue was about and if I can reverse my decision.

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice: Giving the eyes to her changes the music at Firelink Shrine to a more darker tune.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry.

She asked whether you want

> to see the world without the fire

Now, when you agreed, 'bad' ending become available for you, but you still can choose another one.

The choice will be available

> after defeating final boss near bonfire

Comment: To answer the 2nd part of the question: You can reverse your decision by killing her. After that she will reappear at the bonfire.